# How to get Direction after cueBall collide with any ball in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, game-physics

I am creating one pool table unity game. I want to get the direction of ball to show user where the ball will move. Consider the following image for an example.

[image]

Here A is our cueBall and B is ball on the table. Let's consider that when user hit ball A in the direction as per "DIR 1" it will hit to ball B at that time ball A will be at the position of C as per image.

Now I want to know there point

1. How to find position of c.
2. What is the touch point of B & C means which place A will collide with B.
3. In which direction ball B will move after collide by A.

I hope this Question is clear to all and provide proper detail for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Rigidbody on your balls, you could use :

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html

you will use your 'DIR1' as the parameter of the SweepTest function.

Once it returned a 'true' and confirmed a collision, you could use the RaycastHit.distance and 'DIR1' to calculate position 'C'

With position 'C', RaycastHit.point(impact position), and position 'B', you could now calculate 'DIR2'.

--

Physics.Capsule cast is also another option > http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.CapsuleCast.html

Comment: SweepTest method is much more close to my solution but not the excat one for which I am looking for.